# Python grequests with custom header

Tags: python, asynchronous, http-headers, request

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555292/ideal-method-for-sending-multiple-http-requests-over-python/10559969#10559969) about sending asynchronous requests with grequests.

```
import grequests

urls = [
    'http://www.heroku.com',
    'http://tablib.org',
    'http://httpbin.org',
    'http://python-requests.org',
    'http://kennethreitz.com'
]

rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
grequests.map(rs)
```

---

Let's say for just **one** of the url, I wanted to send a custom header:

```
header = {'authorization' : '...'}
```

How would I send a custom header for one url using grequests?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You simply include the header in the arguments like you would with requests.get().

```
header = {'authorization' : '...'}
rs = (grequests.get(u, headers=header) for u in urls)
grequests.map(rs)
```